# Como fazer rolagem automatica

Tags: ajax, css3, front-end, rolamento, xhtml

estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde o usuário faz uma pergunta e o servidor entrega uma resposta, estou com o problema em fazer com que a barra de rolagem vá acompanhando a conversa, até o momento estou tendo o histórico da conversa na tela porém tenho que arrastar com o mouse para ver as novas mensagens.
Estou utilizando JSF com AJAX .

```
<div id="perguntaResposta">
                <ul class="messages">
                    <h:panelGroup id="dialogo">
                        <ui:repeat var="conversa" value="#{chat.conversas}">
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{conversa.usuario == 1}">
                                <li class="message right appeared">
                                    <div class="avatar"></div>
                                    <div class="text_wrapper">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{conversa.intereacaoFala}" />
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{conversa.usuario == 2}">
                                <li class="message left appeared">
                                    <div class="avatar"></div>
                                    <div class="text_wrapper">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{conversa.intereacaoFala}"/>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Testei dessa forma aqui e deu certo, tenta pra ver.

```
<div id="peguntaResposta" style="height:100px;overflow-y:scroll" id="test"></div>
```

É importante lembrar que tem que ter um `height` inicial, o `overflow-y`, é para exibir apenas barra na vertical, `auto` seria para não aparecer se não precisa-se, caso não der certo tenta também `overflow:scroll`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Marcos, mas não deu certo :/